# How to iterate two different DataTable in one loop if both having different rows

Tags: c#

I want to map the Maths and physics dataset rows into single class object which is ExamComposite having property Maths and Physics. If dtMaths and dtPhysics having different rows then how to iterate with a single loop ?

```
  public List<ExamComposite> BindExamComposite(DataSet dsSubjects, int SubID)
        {
            var dtMaths= dsSubjects.Tables[2].Select($"SUBJECT_ID={SubID}").CopyToDataTable();
            var dtPhysics = dsSubjects.Tables[4].Select($"SUBJECT_ID={SubID}").CopyToDataTable();

            var mListExamListComposite = new List<ExamComposite>();
            if (dtMemberMonth.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                var item = new ExamComposite();

                foreach (DataRow dtMath in dtMaths.Rows)
                {

                    item._Mathsobj = mMathsRepository.Map(dtMath);

                    mListExamListComposite.Add(item);
                }

                foreach (DataRow Physics in dtPhysics.Rows)
                {
                    item._Physicsobj = mPhysicsRepository.Map(Physics);
                    mListExamListComposite.Add(item);
                }

            }
            return mListExamListComposite ;
        }
```

Comment: Instead of iterating, try the method as mentioned in this post [Merge columns of two DataTables using linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46881730/merge-columns-of-two-datatables-using-linq)

Comment: Actually my requirement is one object of ExamComposite type containing two different Properties Maths and Physics so i can't apply merge in my condition thanks.

Comment: Assuming the tables have the same number of rows ... `for(int i = 0; i < dtMaths.Rows.Count; i++) { var item = new ExamComposite(dtMaths[i], dtPhysics[i]); mListExamListCompositeListList.Add(item); }`.  You'll need an ExamComposite constructor that takes arguments and you might want to rename your list.

Comment: You cannot apply indexing with [] of type **datatable** which is dtMaths and dtPhysics

Comment: Can you give a little example how the source tables could look like and how you expect the result?